# Is it possible to compress webrtc codec?

Tags: webrtc, webrtc-android

I am an Android developer
Is it possible to compress and modify session codecs programmed with webrtc?
I'm going to publish an app for those who do not want to use a lot of internet in online meetings.

Comment: You want to compress the codec itself? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: The audio and video codecs (opus, VP8, H.264, etc) implemented in WebRTC already do a near-optimal job of compressing the streams WebRTC transmits from device to device.  For video, reducing the width-height resolution of the image is the best way to get further reductions.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i want data saver for my app. I came up with this method. Do you suggest another method?

Comment: @O.Jones   It is a good method. Do you suggest a library for this method?

Comment: Do you know the difference between the codec and the stream it encodes? The codec is the piece of software doing the coding or decoding (hence the name), not the actual stream.